# Proving Goldbach's conjecture (hypothetically) - probabilistic argument

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving

Part $1$.

If $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ by the prime number theorem, can we treat $\frac{1}{\ln(n)} $ as the probability that a number less than $n$ is a prime number?

Say we have some operation $\Delta : n\Delta e = n-e,n+e $  so that $n\Delta_{+}e = 2n $, could we prove Goldbach's conjecture by showing that $ \frac{n}{\ln(n)\ln(2n)} \geq 1$ ?

Part $2$.

Suppose we know that in the interval $[1,p^2_x)$, the number of prime numbers is $ \geq\frac{2(p^2_{x}-1)}{p_{x}+1}$ and in the interval $[p^2_{x},p^2_{y})$, the number of prime numbers is $\geq \frac{2(p^2_{y}-p^2_{x})}{p_{x}+p_y}$.

Can we treat $\frac{2}{p_{x}+1}$ as the lowest probability that a natural number less than $p^2_{x}$ is prime, and $\frac{2}{p_{x}+p_y}$ as the lowest possibility that a natural number between $p^2_{x}$ and $p^2_{y}$ are prime, and assume these probabilities are independent of each other?

Could we then prove Goldbach's conjecture by showing that $\frac{2\times2\times (p^2_{x}-1)}{(p_{x}+1)\times(p_{x}+p_{y})} = \frac{4(p_{x}-1)}{p_{x}+p_{y}} \geq1$ when the following conditions are true:

a) $p^2_{x}\leq n<2n<p^2_{y}$

b) $p^2_{x}\leq n<p^2_{x+1}$ and $p^2_{x}<2n\leq 2(p^2_{x+1}-1) : \frac{4(p_{x}-1)}{p_{x}+2(p^2_{x+1}-1)} \geq 1$

c) $\exists p_{y}: 3p_{x}-4 \geq p_{y}> \sqrt{2(p^2_{x+1}-1)} \because \frac{4(p_{x}-1)}{p_{x}+p_{y}} \geq1\implies 3p_{x}-4 \geq p_{y}$

Comment: I am far from this field of research, but having seen many presentations of this nature of difficult number-theoretic conjectures, I'd have to say that this will never get any closer to being a proof than what you wrote, because none of your probabilistic arguments are rigorously true in the simplicity you state them.  To see what kind of rigor seems to be necessary, you should glance at Helfgott's recent proof of the weak Goldbach conjecture, and see what kinds of details concerned him.  They're all very specific error estimates.

Comment: That's not to say that Helfgott's proof is even probabilistic in nature.  It's just that the difference between what he wrote and what was previously known is at a much different level than what's written here.  This is also not to evaluate the correctness of anything you wrote.  I'm just shooting down the strategy.

Comment: To see why this kind of argument cannot possibly work, consider that it would equally well prove that any _odd_ number is the sum of two prime numbers. Something to which counterexamples are known to exist (in abundance).

Comment: @RyanReich: Dear Ryan, Regarding "the difference between what he [Helfgott] wrote and what was previously known", note that Vinagradov long ago had proved weak Goldbach for all sufficiently large odd integers (and introduced one of the fundamental methods in analytic number theory in doing so); Helfgott's contribution is to replace "all sufficiently large" by "all".  The point of my (admittedly tangential) comment is that the attribution for weak Goldbach should be to Vinagradov as much as Helfgott.  Regards,

Comment: @Matt you are quite right, and it is actually this very point that I had in mind for the difference. Helfgott improved the lower bound on "sufficiently large"to the point where a computer search could finish the proof. This improvement was achieved (as far as I know) by a serious refinement of error terms, not by implementing any kind of heuristic like the one above. (You know this, of course, but I just wanted to make it clear in general.)

Comment: @RyanReich: Dear Ryan, Thanks for the response.  I think your description of Helfgott's contribution is pretty accurate, and certainly it has little in common with the ideas in the OP's discussion!  Best wishes,

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I'm not sure I agree, and would love to see that in action. I don't think we could prove odd numbers are the sum of two primes using this method, because it relies on finding the probability that n+e and n-e are prime only because n-e+n+e = 2n not 2n+1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a very simple reason why such approach cannot work, unless you combine it with very special properties of prime numbers.

Let

$$A := \{ 3 \lfloor \frac{n \ln n}{3} \rfloor | n \in \mathbb N  \}$$

Note that the probability that a number is in $A$ is also $\frac{1}{\ln n}$, and every reasoning in your tentative proof also applies to this set $A$.

If your method is successful, then it also applies to this $A$, and can prove that any positive integer is the sum of two elements in $A$.

But all elements in $A$ are multiple of $3$....

Comment: Hi, was just wondering if you could show exactly how this would show all positive integers are the sum of multiples of 3, because the method I used relies on finding the probability that both n-e and n+e have a certain property (primality), but they both cannot be multiples of 3.

Comment: @BradGraham My point is that the probability that $n+e$ is prime is the same as the probability that $n+e \in A$. Same way the probability that $n-e$ by itself is a prime is the same as the probability of $n-e \in A$. So, unless you have extra conditions which relate the probabilities that $n-e, n+e$ are both primes, which is exactly what you need to prove, the probabilities working with the prime sets and the probabilities working with A are the same....

Comment: @BradGraham And the point is really: you cannot prove probabilistically that both cannot be multiple of $3$, but you can do all the computations in your question with these two sets.....

Comment: I see what you mean

Comment: Maybe I don't... You cannot prove probabilistically that both n+e and n-e cannot be a multiple of 3, but we can prove that is true using other methods like modular arithmetic. You can actually prove that n-e and n+e can both be primes by setting n as 8 and e as 3 for example.